# Cannot use boost::shared_mutex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mutex

I have a small template class with a non-static member of type `boost::shared_mutex`. Whenever I try to compile it, I get the error:

`'boost::shared_mutex::shared_mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::shared_mutex'`.

`boost::shared_mutex` really has a private nested class `shared_mutex`, but I don't understand why this problem arose.

Here's my class:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
#include <queue>

template <typename T>
class CThreadSafeQueue
{
public:
    CThreadSafeQueue();

private:
    boost::mutex    _sharedMutex;
    std::queue<T>   _queue;
};

template <typename T>
CThreadSafeQueue<T>::CThreadSafeQueue()
{

}
```

The same happens with a regular `boost::mutex'.

I have another, non-template class, in which I have no problem using either mutex type.

Comment: can you post the corresponding code.

Comment: What version of boost are you using? I successfully compiled the code (with instantiation of template `CThreadSafeQueue<int> x;`) with boost 1.47.0 using compiler VC2010.

Comment: I got compilation failure when I attempt to invoke `CThreadSafeQueue<int>` copy constructor, as @tune2fs has already indicated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Huh! The solution to my problems turned out to be very simple yet very hard to find. I was only having problems with methods declared `const`, because lockers are mutating mutexes. All I had to do was make it `mutable`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the class noncopyable, or implement your own copy and assignment operator. `boost::mutex` is non copyable, therefore you get this error.

You can derive your class from `boost::noncopyable`, to make it noncopyable.

Comment: That seems to help, but now I wonder how can my other class that also uses `boost::mutex` compile successfully. I didn't override copy constructor and assignment operator in that class...

Comment: In the worst case you can use a static mutex, this will kill your performance however, but it works.

Comment: Ironically, my original intent was to implement lock-free queue to avoid locking at all:)